# Configuring Worklight Application Center download/install

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I have the Worklight 6.1 Application Center installed on a server.

Users install from the the Application Center by visiting a url on their mobile browser. Clicking the Install button downloads the mobile app.  But when the mobile user taps the Install button, the mobile browser window does not close, so the user gets no feedback that the download is occurring.

How can the behavior of the Install button be configured to make sure the browser window closes when the install begins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the mobile operating system you are using when visiting the installers.html URL and clicking on the Install button.

In:

- Android: a "Downloading..." toast message is displayed
- iOS 7: the mobile Safari app goes to the background and you can see the application being installed
- iOS 8: the mobile Safari app will not go to the background

In iOS, Apple does not expose any APIs to the developer in order to provide visual cues as an application is being downloaded.

Comment: Thanks Lior. So enterprise app deployment is broken in iOS 8. I filed bug report # 18926181 with Apple. And I added an Open Radar as well: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4932826914881536